# SKLabelNodes not responding to the "isHidden" property in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my app, I am attempting to hide/show some SKLabelNodes in SpriteKit. However, despite them having the .isHidden property, they do not seem to update, and instead stay visible. They also do not respond to other properties such as opacity changes or text changes.

```
player1TurnLabel.isHidden = true
```

This is the code I am using to try to hide the SKLabelNode (I am using Swift 4), but -- as I said before -- no visible changes are made when the app is running.

Comment: Trying with a small sample project, `isHidden` property works perfectly as expected. You may have some faults in other parts of your code. Try to create a complete, minimal code to reproduce your issue, and show whole code. One possible reason is that your `player1TurnLabel` is another thing than the `SKLabelNode` displayed on the screen.